# CoffeeScript Packages Not Working with Meteor 0.9.0.1

Tags: meteor

After upgrading to 0.9.0.1 it would seem that CoffeeScript packages have two problems:

- The exports from package.js don't seem to be exported.
- The source files don't seem to be compiled.

package.js:

```
    Package.describe({
       summary: "sunburn"
    });

    Package.on_use(function (api, where) {

       api.add_files(['lib/sunburn.coffee'], 'server');

       api.export && api.export('Stinger', 'server');


    });

    Package.on_test(function (api) {
    });
```

sunburn.coffee:

```
Stinger = -> "stinger here"
```

This is a local package. Both 'meteor add sunburn' and 'meteor remove sunburn' work fine. If sunburn.coffee is modified the server restarts. However, 'Stinger' is undefined when used from the server-side code. Somewhat more interestingly, if sunburn.coffee is modified to include syntax errors, the server will happily restart and no error will be reported. This is what leads me to believe that the CoffeeScript files aren't even being compiled. Or, at least, not being fully "wired up".

Code similar to this worked in the pre 0.9 version.

One last note: if the sunburn.coffee is changed to be a normal js file, 'Stinger' rewritten as normal javascript, and the file path updated in package.js, the above works fine.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that your package actually depends on coffeescript to make the compilation happen :

```
api.use("coffeescript","client");
```

Previously, only having your app depending on build plugins (less, coffeescript, etc...) was OK but apparently now you have to specify that you use them inside packages as well.

Unrelated, but you should also specify a version in your Package.describe, and testing for the existence of api.export is unrelevant because I hope nobody is using Meteor < 0.6.5 anymore.